# Convert absolute frequency data to raw data

Tags: r, data-conversion

I have absolute frequency-data from 4 electronic distributors representing how many power supplies they offer for a certain power-class (measured in watt). I want to convert this data into raw data, so that I can create a boxplot for the 4 distributors and some other analysis.
I already tried the R function `melt()` of reshape2-lib, but it treats the absolute frequencies as measurement-values.

The data (absolute frequencies) I have looks like this:

```
power_in_watt digikey farnell mouser rs
1                   0       0      0  2
2                   0       0      0  1
4                   1       0      1  3
5                   2       0      0  3
6                   2       1      2  3
...
```

The raw data I would like to have:

```
distributor power_in_watt
rs                      1
rs                      1
rs                      2
digikey                 4
mouser                  4
rs                      4
rs                      4
rs                      4
digikey                 5
digikey                 5
rs                      5
rs                      5
rs                      5
digikey                 6
digikey                 6
farnell                 6
mouser                  6
mouser                  6
rs                      6
rs                      6
rs                      6
rs                      6
...
```

Is there any way to convert this automatically (preferably in R)?

Comment: Also, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518728/r-replicate-each-row-of-an-r-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534296/expanding-a-frequency-table-where-the-variable-names-are-the-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a one liner base `R`:

```
stack(lapply(df[-1], rep, x=df[,1]))

#   values     ind
#1       4 digikey
#2       5 digikey
#3       5 digikey
#4       6 digikey
#5       6 digikey
#6       6 farnell
#7       4  mouser
#8       6  mouser
#9       6  mouser
#10      1      rs
#11      1      rs
#12      2      rs
#13      4      rs
#14      4      rs
#15      4      rs
#16      5      rs
#17      5      rs
#18      5      rs
#19      6      rs
#20      6      rs
#21      6      rs
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(power_in_watt = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L), digikey = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 2L), farnell = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), mouser = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 2L), rs = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("power_in_watt", 
"digikey", "farnell", "mouser", "rs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: seems to do exactly what I want. where can I enter the data object which contains the csv?

Comment: the data object is the dataframe df! Yes it does what you want target of an answer ;)

Comment: Well sorry, was a bit confused at first by the function call inside.. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I gather that what you want is to replicate the rows based on the given frequencies.

First, we put the data in long form with `tidyr`, a successor library to `reshape2`.

```
> library(tidyr)
> df.long <- df %>% gather(distributor, count, -power_in_watt)
> df.long
   power_in_watt distributor count
1              1     digikey     0
2              2     digikey     0
3              4     digikey     1
4              5     digikey     2
5              6     digikey     2
6              1     farnell     0
7              2     farnell     0
8              4     farnell     0
9              5     farnell     0
10             6     farnell     1
11             1      mouser     0
```

We can then expand the rows based on the count using base R

```
> df.long[rep(1:nrow(df.long)), df.long$count), ]
     power_in_watt distributor count
3                4     digikey     1
4                5     digikey     2
4.1              5     digikey     2
5                6     digikey     2
5.1              6     digikey     2
10               6     farnell     1
13               4      mouser     1
15               6      mouser     2
15.1             6      mouser     2
16               1          rs     2
16.1             1          rs     2
17               2          rs     1
```

EDIT: A closer read leads me to refine my answer

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The solution you found does more or less what `melt()` does ... the values in the "count"-column are still absolute frequencies. i want to have a single row for every entry, e.g. if there are 2 power supplies available in the 5 watt category at digikey, i want two single lines, each "digikey" => 5

Comment: I realized the underlying question after I posted my initial answer, and I've edited to reflect.

Comment: if there are 0 power supplies available for a watt-category at a distributor, no lines should be created for that one